# Setting seperate log file for hook plugin in Liferay

Tags: logging, log4j, liferay, liferay-6

Is it possible to have seperate log file for hook plugin in Liferay using Apache Log4j?

Answer (score 0):

Liferay use apache log4j to deal with log file.

In log4j you can separate log by package. So if all your hook plugin start with the same package you can override portal-log4j-ext.xml and create appender like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
       <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
           <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
              <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm:ss,SSS}|%-5p|%t|%c{1}:%L|%X{user}|%m%n" />
           </layout>
       </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_1" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="@liferay.home@/logs/file1.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_2" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="@liferay.home@/logs/file2.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender> 

    <category name="com.test.package1" additivity="false">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_1" />
    </category>
    <category name="com.test.package1" additivity="false">
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_2" />
    </category>
</log4j:configuration>
```